# ggplot2: Time-series plot by continuous variable, color/fill by group

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I have searched considerably for what I want to accomplish, but I haven't run across examples or plots that are specifically what I'm looking for), so I am reaching out to the community.

**What I have** (data downloadable [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Ur94JBEbWqVDRQUDRMMTdBbUk)):

Time-series data (each record 2 hours apart and spanning nearly a year) with associated elevation and property ownership.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv("dataex.csv")
data$timestamp <-as.POSIXct(as.character(data$timestamp),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="GMT")
```

**What I want** (via ggplot):

A line or bar plot showing elevation (y-axis) across time (x-axis) for each data record colored by ownership (for a line plot, filling the area under the line, or for a bar plot, filling the bar). I've tried iterations of `geom_line`, `geom_bar`, and `geom_area` (w `geom_bar` below the closest I have come). I'd like at least one of the following options to come true!

**Option A** - The closest I have come to achieving this (plotting per data record) is with the following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=timestamp, y=elev, fill=OWNER)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

However, I'd like the bars to be touching each other, but if I adjust the `width` in `geom_bar()`, everything disappears. (Also, if I run the above code on other batches of similar data, it will only show a fraction of the bars, likely because they have more data records). Seems like its just too much data to plot. So I tried another route...

**Option B** - Plotting by day, which turns out to be more informative, showing each day the variability in ownership.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=as.Date(Date, format='%Y-%m-%d'), y=elev, fill=OWNER)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)
```

However, this sums the y-axis, so the elevation is not interpretable. I could divide the y-axis by 12 (the typical number of records per day) but there are occasional days with fewer than 12 records, which causes the y-axis to be incorrect. Is there a function or a way to divide the y-axis by the respective number of records per day that is being represented in the plot? Or does someone have advice for a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)

readr::read_csv("~/Desktop/dataex.csv") %>% 
  mutate(timestamp=lubridate::mdy_hm(timestamp)) %>% 
  select(timestamp, elev, Owner=OWNER) -> df

ggplot(df, aes(timestamp, elev, group=Owner, color=Owner)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=timestamp, yend=0), size=0.1) +
  scale_x_datetime(expand=c(0,0), date_breaks="2 months") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,2250), label=scales::comma) +
  ggthemes::scale_color_tableau() +
  hrbrmisc::theme_hrbrmstr(grid="Y") +
  labs(x=NULL, y="Elevation") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(angle=0, margin=margin(r=-20)))
```

[image]

?

Comment: Excellent! That is a very nice solution to Option A. Thank you so very much.